# Is it possible to use SSRS data set name as a parameter?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dataset

Is there a way to use Data Set name as a parameter ?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: What is the purpose of that? If you want the user selects the dataset to run the report there is another approach to do that. If you want to show the name of the dataset in the report you will have to pass it from the dataset or hardcode it in the report.

Comment: Yes, I want user to select the dataset to run there report. how do I do that?

Comment: Use a stored procedure to control what dataset to use by passing it to the sp. Then you'll only need to return 1 dataset in the report.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Text` data type parameter, in the `Report Parameter Properties` window, go to `Available values` tab and select the `Specify values` radio button.

Add a Label and a Value per dataset, then create a dataset and use the parameter to conditionally run the query based on the selected dataset.

For example:

```
IF @DataSetSelection = 'Report1'
select * from Table --Select statement for Report1
ELSE
  BEGIN
    IF @DataSetSelection = 'Report2'
      select * from Table --Select statement for Report2
    ELSE
      IF @DataSetSelection = 'Report3'
        select * from Table --Select statement for Report3
      ELSE
        IF @DataSetSelection = 'Report4'
          select * from Table --Select statement for Report4
  END
```

Also as mentioned by WEI_DBA in comments you can wrap that logic in a SP and pass the SSRS parameter value to the SP.